# Why does 7-Zip's compression speed lower over time?

Tags: compression, zip, 7-zip

I'm busy backing up my local server files, which amounts to just under 4GB of data in ~295000 files. I selected `7z` as the format, and set the level to `Store`.

The process started pretty quickly, but the speed has dropped from 9MB/s to 1MB/s (and lowering) over a period of half an hour. The estimated completion time has also gone up quite considerably, and continues to rise.

Any reason as to why this is the case? Is the speed indication shown the *actual* current speed, or is it some kind of average?

**Edit:** As a side note, this obviously only happens with a large sequence of small files. When it gets to the larger files towards the end of the 'queue', it speeds up as one would expect it to.

Comment: Not use 7-zip to compress test Winrar)

Comment: @STTR - I have used WinRAR in the past, but it isn't freeware. If the speed is truly spectacular, then I will consider buying it. Otherwise, I believe it's better to stick with freeware. (I also think it's a tad expensive.)

Comment: Sorry, but normal testing archivers I did not come across that very sad. In tests, no fundamental things. Comparisons between a 32 and 64 bit versions of the archiver. Tables with speed archiving and compression, and compression ratio. Tests on different data sets. Archiving and unpacking archiver in preferred formats. Tests on different numbers of cores and priorities.

Comment: As you're saying you're using "Store", then you won't get any compression at all. You might actually be limited by performance of your file system then? (Just a wild guess.)

Comment: @Arjan - I generally use 'Store' for backups because of the faster read times. Can't quite tell if it has something to do with the file-system. Could also be a fragmentation thing, I guess. Perhaps I should try on Linux to see if it remains consistent?

Answer (score -1):

`Store` has no compression.If you are only trying to backup all files without compression then use zip format with `store` in 7-zip.
It should take less time than 7z(7z will give you best compression ratio than rar, zip, tar etc.)Rar is best in speed/compression ratio. 
So use Winrar(Winrar is 40 day trial softwar without license). You can reinstall winrar to reset the trial.

*Use ccleaner that might speed up your system*.

Comment: is this an anwer really. this should be posted as comment.

Comment: @FranciscoTapia I know but i don't have  enough rep to comment.For the question i think this is enough.

Comment: i invite you to check http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation