# Why does write speed constantly slow down in 7zip during compression?

Tags: ssd, performance, compression, speed, 7-zip

> Related Question:
>   [Why does 7-Zip's compression speed lower over time?](https://superuser.com/questions/892197/why-does-7-zips-compression-speed-lower-over-time)

So I am compressing files (particulatarly large files, ≥1GB). So I notice that the write speed is slowing down and the required time increasing. Unfortunately, it keeps on slowing down although it takes longer to slow down over time. It rapidly drops with a high write speed, and it slowly drops with slow write speed. What is causing this and why does this occur?
How can this be fixed?

Comment: Compressing using what format? All? 7z? Zip? LZ5? Have you tested?

Comment: 7z and has been tested.

Comment: 7-Zip uses all CPU cores of your system. Compressing large files will cause your CPU to run constantly with 100% on all cores. Therefore the heat is accumulating and may overload your cooling system after a certain time which forces the CPU to run slower and slower... Use CPU temperature monitoring tool and you will see that the CPU temperature is going higher and higher and the CPU frequency is going down. Also keep in mind that the compression speed bases on the data you compress. If data can be easily compressed the write rate is higher.

Comment: Even if I set it to 2 out of 4 threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"How can it be fixed?" - There is nothing to fix, as it is working as intended.

As far as 7-Zip (or any program writing a large file) is concerned, the file is being created and written to disk.  However, that is not what is happening.  The operating system is writing the file to its [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)).  The file cache is RAM dedicated to speed up reads and writes to slower disks.  The OS eventually dumps its cache to disk as it fills up and/or that chunk of the file is not being used.  This is why the write speeds are so high at the beginning, as the file as going into the high speed RAM cache.  Once the cache fills and/or the fcache is being purged the file gets written to the slower disk, the write rate slows down significantly.  The write speed is measured as an overall average, so starting high, then ending low causes the write speed to slowly descend.

Comment: LoL another drive-by downvote.  This is the correct answer.

Comment: So you mean when the cache is empty, there is less of the file in there as 7zip compresses it. So there is less to write, therefore it correlates to slower write speeds?

Comment: @Phoenix Yes and no.  Its complicated.  You can read up on file caches in the link in my answer to learn more.  7-zip is writing the files to disk, but instead of actually going to disk, its going into the cache.  Thats why its fast.  Since the file is BIG the cache fills up and it starts to dump it to disk and fill up with more data being written.

Comment: So the only way is to increase the RAM?

Comment: @Phoenix You are still looking at this as if it a problem to be fixed.  There is nothing to fix.  There is no problem.  Yes, you can throw more money/hardware at it and make it go faster, but the same thing will happen, just slightly ffaster.

Comment: @Phoenix I see you accepted it, but I just thought of another way of looking at it.  You are complaining about the speed decreasing.  You could remove the cache and the speed would be  consistent.  Not slowing down at all.  However, that consistent speed would much slower and take more time overall.

Comment: But it is a notebook, I can't simply pull out the RAM.

Comment: @Phoenix Lol.  It was a hypothetical.  No one would actually do this.  I just wanted to show that the thing making the inconsistency is actually a *good* thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106178/discussion-between-phoenix-and-keltari).

Comment: What happens if my ssd is faster than my memory.

Comment: @wonsuc Since there are no SSDs faster than RAM, the question doesnt make any sense.  However, lets just say for the sake of argument that there are SSDs faster than RAM.  Well...  Then we would no longer be using RAM.